# Configure phpMyAdmin with multiple databases and http auth?

Tags: mysql, authentication, configuration, phpmyadmin

I want to configure phpMyAdmin to access multiple mysql servers, and use "http auth" login (with mysql database login). However it does not seem to work and I am not sure if it is possible or not ? Of course I first have read dozens of documentations, forums, and webpages without any information on tihs.

This is my configuration (works with the first server only) :

```
/* Server: svrdb01 [1] */
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'svrdb01';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '10.128.1.1';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'http';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_http_realm'] = 'Login MySQL 1';
/* Server: svrdb02 [2] */
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'svrdb02';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '10.128.1.2';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'http';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_http_realm'] = 'Login MySQL 2';
/* Server: svrdb04 [3] */
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'svrdb04';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '10.128.1.4';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'http';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_http_realm'] = 'Login MySQL 3';
```

Any help would be useful, especially on these 3 questions :

1. Is it possible to configure phpMyAdmin with that logic ?
2. If yes, will phpMyAdmin try the login on each successive server until success ?
3. If not, is there another way to have phpMyAdmin use the MySQL login with multiple servers ?

Thanks a lot for your help...

P. S. I asked that question on serverfault already but nobody was able to answer the question and I got one downvote without any explanation. I hope someone on stackoverflow will be able to answer the question (or tell me what's wrong with my question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said this configuration file "works with the first server only" - what does that mean exactly? Do you get an error when trying to change to the other servers? Are you expecting a prompt before login to ask you which server you wish to connect to? I'm curious because this seems to work for me, but the interface is different than the one used by auth_type cookie which might be confusing.

With auth_type cookie, the login form on the first page has fields for username, password, and a dropdown for selecting the host. With auth_type http, you get the HTTP browser login page for username and password, and have to enter the username or password for the first server here. Then, once connected to the first server, the you can use the server dropdown in the navigation pane to pick another server (this dropdown also appears with the other auth_types). I find this less convenient because I first have to connect to my first server before connecting to a different one, so I use auth_type cookie (which also lets me log out and gives better error reporting when something goes wrong).

You could force the server by entering a [customized URL](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/faq.html#can-i-access-directly-to-database-or-table-pages) (or bookmarking one); something like https://localhost/phpmyadmin/index.php?server=5, but even that seems to require authenticating to both servers (1 and 5) before I can actually do anything.

To answer your questions directly:

> Is it possible to configure phpMyAdmin with that logic ?

Sure, this works fine.

> If yes, will phpMyAdmin try the login on each successive server until success ?

No, you have to log in to the first server, then jump to the other server to which you wish to connect.

> If not, is there another way to have phpMyAdmin use the MySQL login with multiple servers ?

auth_type cookie is the best, but even using auth_type http works as long as you're aware of the limitations and are willing to work around them.

In summary, I suggest switching to auth_type cookie because I find that easiest to work with.

Comment: Dear @Isaac thanks a lot for your complete and detailed answer ! I think I solved the problem thank to you. But first I will comment with answers to your questions and things I discovered.

Comment: First of all, to answer your first question : "works with the first server only" means that I can login and use phpmyadmin if I enter a login/password valid on the first server. But if I enter a login/password valid on the second server I can't login at all. As you said it works if logging to the first server and the change server and login again. But this is of course an unwanted behavior as users that should login to the third server should not have access to the first ;-)

Comment: Then, yes I know it works with auth_cookie, and of course you can select server before logging. But first of all I would like to avoid cookies for security reasons but moreover I do not want customers to get the list of all our databases servers. Some are specific to customers and should not be public.

Comment: Now about the solution I think I solved the problem ! Your idea to add the server number in the URL was the right one. It took me one hour and some debug to understand all the login and authentication process but I think it is now clear, and the solution is to use the following URL :

https://localhost/phpmyadmin/?server=5

Answer (score 0):

The solution, based on @Isaac Bennetch answer is to use the following URL :

- https://localhost/phpmyadmin/?server=5

Note that index.php must NOT be included in the URL otherwise it won't work.

After analysis this is the code that is being executed :

1. libraries/plugins/auth/AuthenticationHttp.class.php - public function authSetUser() - login and password are defined
2. libraries/dbi/mysqli.dbi.lib.php - function PMA_DBI_connect()
3. same file - function PMA_DBI_real_connect() - real connection to the database

If you add debug on these places, then you can check which server is used and see that "?server=5" selects the right server.