# A server NOT specified in config.inc.php IS shown in phpMyAdmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

I know this question is similar to
[A server specified in config.inc.php is not shown in phpMyAdmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62324352/a-server-specified-in-config-inc-php-is-not-shown-in-phpmyadmin/)
However that question is about getting additional servers to show, and that I do not have a problem with. I want to remove one.

How does one remove "localhost" The older version worked fine, but since upgrading to the latest version localhost shows in the dropdown and I would like to remove it.

I can add additional servers at will, they all work, but I just want to remove the local host as a login option

```
declare(strict_types=1);

$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'notshown';

/**
 * Servers configuration
 */
$i = 0;

/**
 * First server
 */
$i++;

/* Authentication type listed below */
/*$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie'; */

/* Server parameters */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;

/* Server: sqlname [1] */
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'sqlname';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'private ip';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '3306';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['UploadDir'] = '/foldername';
$cfg['SaveDir'] = '/foldername/';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;

/* Server: sqlname [2] */
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'sqlname';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'private ip';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '3306';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['UploadDir'] = '/foldername';
$cfg['SaveDir'] = '/foldername/';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
```

I have tried a number of things, such as removing the first server since the config on previous install didn't have it, and most will return an error, such as invalid server index 0 (even though login still works on the listed servers)

I just want localhost to not be an option, and in fact the word localhost does not even exist in the config.inc.php filename and there is not a local host on the network.

All other functions of phpmyadmin work. This site that runs phpmyadmin is running on a windows host, however the mysql servers are running on linux throughout the network accessible only by private ip.

I know I am likely missing something simple

Answer (score 0):

A friend of mine helped me figure this out, the order at the beginning just needed changed slightly. Below is the code that works. Additional servers can be added at will, and local host does not show unless you want one.

```
declare(strict_types=1);

$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'notshown';
$cfg['UploadDir'] = '/foldername';
$cfg['SaveDir'] = '/foldername/';

/**
 * Servers configuration
 */
$i = 0;
/**
 * First server
 */

/* Authentication type listed below */
/*$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie'; */

/* Server parameters */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;

/* Server: sqlname [1] */
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'sqlname';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'private ip';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '3306';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['UploadDir'] = '/foldername';
$cfg['SaveDir'] = '/foldername/';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;

/* Server: sqlname [2] */
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'sql2';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'private ip';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '3306';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
/**
```